# livecode building standalone for iOS error: There was an error while saving the standalone application linking for armv7 failed with Id:

Tags: ios, livecode

I just downloaded and installed Livecode Community 6.0 and tried to create a standalone of my app.
  [image]

[image]

BTW Livecode 5.5.4 works fine.

Any idea what's causing this?

Answer (score 1):

My reading of the error says you're trying to build a standalone for the simulator (i386) and yet trying to link it for the device (armv7).

Is that a setting you've got wrong?

I haven't tried this with LiveCode Community 6.0 myself.

Comment: I didn't change any settings between 5.5.4 and 6.0.  When 5.5.4 runs it creates the standalone just fine.  When 6.0 runs the simulator works, but the standalone creation fails with the error. I'm not sure where to look.

Answer (score 1):

Check in Preferences under Mobile Support and see if iOS SDK is linked. Should be a green light if 5.1 and 6.1 are linked and available. Should also have text that states "Available device SDKs: 5.1,6.1" and "Available simulators: 5.1,6.1"

Comment: Thomas, I've SDKs 5.1, 6.0 & 6.1 and Simulators 5.0, 5.1, 6.0 & 6.1 showing.  I've linked the current version of Xcode along with 4.4.1 and 4.5.2